# Ubuntu for ARM and AMD64 compatibility

Tags: application-development

I am going to develop some applications for ubuntu running on AMD64.
What I am curious about is will my application work for ubuntu running on ARM?
I am noob on OS.

Comment: No, it won't. You may recompile for the ARM architecture you want.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Not quite so simple. Depends on language and dependencies being used, etc…

Comment: @dobey Of course. That's why I posted a hinting comments and you a proper answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It depends.* To run on a different architecture, your app will have to be compiled on that architecture, and written such that it will compile successfully, and not have issues. For compiled languages anyway. Interpreted languages may run from the same package, regardless of architecture, with similar considerations.

If you want to build applications which work across multiple architectures, you will have to take the differences between those architectures into consideration when developing the app, and build separate binaries for each architecture.